# Which variables should I transform, center, and/or standardize in my data for Principal Component Analysis?

Tags: pca, standardization, binary-data, centering, compositional-data

I have multiple datasets that I am attempting to use principal component analysis (PCA) on in order to infer the underlying structure of the data.  I'm attempting to predict growth increment of conifers (the response which apparently needed to be cube root transformed for my original linear models).  My predictor variables include: continuous (some log-transformed like size-related variables, some compositional, and some traditionally scaled); binary; ordinal; and nominal (of which I'm pretty sure I can order with respect to site productivity).  I'm mostly attempting to make inferences because some of my previous models from linear regression have not produced significant terms corresponding to categories like health or climate and I feel that they should have.  I've read in Joliffe (2002) that I might want to leave my compositional data uncentered.  Forgive my naiveté, but I'm wondering if I should also do this for my binary data.  It also seems that I might not want to scale these since they're already on a 0 - 1 scale but I'm not sure.  After only using my continuous predictors (including compositional variables), it appears that a size principal component makes up the largest portion of the variability and Joliffe also mentions that one might want to attempt a "double-centering" of the log-transformed data if this is the case.  I don't know if this is even possible since the log-transformed data only makes up a small portion of my datasets.  Finally, I should ask if having such a combination of data types will complicate analysis so much that it will make inferences unreliable.  I am currently using R for this analysis.  Thank you.